# C++ return 0; OR return 1; concepts

Tags: c++

basically i want to ask what is the concept of return in c++

??
sometime we usually use return 0; or sometime return 1; It is quite confusing to me Please help me some one

Comment: What context are you talking in? `main()`? Some other function? `main()` *and* some other function?

Answer (score 2):

This is entirely implementation dependent. An interface documentation will usually document what the `1` or the `0` stands for. Typically, they will stand for status of whether the operation for which function was called was a success or a failure.
The C language standard defines two macros for indication failure and success:

```
EXIT_SUCCESS    
EXIT_FAILURE
```

Reference:

**C99 Standard:    7.20.4.3 The `exit` function**
**Para 5**

> Finally, control is returned to the host environment. If the value of status is `zero` or
>   `EXIT_SUCCESS`, an implementation-deﬁned form of the status successful termination is
>   returned. If the value of status is `EXIT_FAILURE` , an implementation-deﬁned form
>   of the status unsuccessful termination is returned. Otherwise the status returned is
>   implementation-deﬁned.